# Gcloud SDK Share Datastore , Blob , Task Queue

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I have three modules (front end and two services) that run on different docker containers and  all of them run the Google SDK.

We are trying to replicate the "services" concept on App Engine, now our problem is that we need to share Datastore/Blobstore between the containers.

Using the storage_path flag allowed me to actually view the data between the containers but any attempt of writing data results in "Database Locked" or it simply hangs

Is this even possible ?
Is it possible to just use one container and start multiple instances of the dev_server while sharing the datastore , etc ?

Comment: what Datastore are you using in your containers? Is it google Datastore or something else?

Comment: @YaronIdan Yes Google Datastore